# NativeBase showing error while using in Jest testing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

I want to test a basic component name **TitleHeader** which uses HStack and VStack from native base.
The component:-

```
import {Center, HStack, VStack} from 'native-base';
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import appColors from '../../constants/appColors';
//Icon Imports
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

import {TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/core';

const TitleHeader = ({
  title = 'Header Title',
  navigationBack = false,
  center = false,
  onBackPress,
  drawer = false,
  style = {},
}) => {
  console.log(title);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleGoBack = () => {
    if (onBackPress && typeof onBackPress === 'function') {
      onBackPress();
    } else if (drawer) {
      navigation.goBack();
    } else {
      navigation.pop();
    }
  };
  return (
    <HStack
      bg={appColors.primaryBlue}
      style={[
        {
          height: 55,
          position: 'relative',
        },
        style,
      ]}
      alignItems="center"
      px={3}>
      {navigationBack ? (
        <View style={{position: 'absolute', zIndex: 10, left: 10}}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={handleGoBack}
            style={{
              width: 35,
              height: 35,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <Ionicons name="arrow-back" size={26} color="white" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      ) : null}
      <VStack flex={1} alignItems="center" pl={2}>
        <Text
          color="white"
          fontSize="lg"
          numberOfLines={1}
          ellipsizeMode="tail"
          style={
            center
              ? {}
              : {
                  width: '80%',
                }
          }>
          {title}
        </Text>
      </VStack>
    </HStack>
  );
};

export default TitleHeader;
```

Following is my test case which uses jest for testing:-

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import TitleHeader from '../src/components/AppHeaders/TitleHeader';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {NativeBaseProvider} from 'native-base';

jest.mock('native-base');
const wrapper = ({children}) => (
  <NativeBaseProvider
    initialWindowMetrics={{
      frame: {x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0},
      insets: {top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0},
    }}>
    {children}
  </NativeBaseProvider>
);
describe('Testing Title Header for screens', () => {
  test('should render title header', () => {
    const tree = renderer
      .create(
        <NavigationContainer>
          <TitleHeader title={'HEADER TEST'} />
        </NavigationContainer>,
        {wrapper},
      )
      .toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

But I am getting this error inspite of using jest.mock('native-base') in my jest.setup.js.
[image]

I am new to testing please help me render this component first and test it using jest. Also, one more thing to add is that if I do not use the wrapper function it throws error telling me that "theme is not defined. Did you forget to wrap your app inside NativeBaseProvider?".

Answer (score 0):

If the component that you trying to test has the theme coming from NativeBase you need to provide the `<ThemeProvider/>` (Spelling might differ depending on the library, in your case `<NativeBaseProvider/>`

If you do jest.mock('native-base') and you do not return anything will cause `Nothing was returned from render` error.

Did you add native-base library to `transformIgnorePatterns` of `jest.config` as suggested in this [issue](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/396#issuecomment-270116326)?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.I have already added native-base to transformIgnorePatterns. Also, regarding the error "Nothing was returned from render", can you please tell me how to write the correct mock for native-base??

Comment: I would also like to know that.